# How to get result of NN, modify result, then pass it to another NN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm a beginner with neural networks planning to use Tensorflow estimators, please bear with me.

Is it possible to get an output from a trained neural network, modify that, then pass the result to another model?

I hope to get a number as an output from the first NN (if this is possible through TensorFlow), make that number undergo some calculations, then pass that to the second NN.

Do I need to use two separate estimators for this? Can I put these two NNs in the same model while being sure the output of the first NN will be a number?

I'm sorry if any of these questions are common sense, but I'm definitely a little lost on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### To easier use of `tf.estimator`

The lack of proper documentation on `tf.estimators` makes this pretty hard problem to solve with `estimators` only.  You would have to define a custom estimator, but as I mentioned, as of today, there is no end-to-end guide on how to accomplish this.
My suggestion would be to define your model via `tf.keras` API and then convert the compiled model to estimator via `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator` (for further information, check [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/estimator/model_to_estimator?version=stable))

#### To join two models

[Keras Lambda Layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda?version=stable) allows defining your custom operations as a model layer.
You could define your two models via, for example `tf.keras.Sequential` and "join" them with your custom lambda layer.

#### (Optional) Unstable Alternative Approach: Subclassing API

You could use [Keras Subclassing API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#building_models) to define your own model class with custom forward pass, that would include your operations. There are however some serialization issues with Subclassing API. From the [Tensorflow Docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize):
`A subclassed model differs in that it's not a data structure, it's a piece of code. The architecture of the model is defined via the body of the call method. This means that the architecture of the model cannot be safely serialized.`

Hence, I'm not sure if this could be safely converted to `tf.estimator`.